# How to set a sqlite pragma using c?

Tags: c, database, sqlite

I want to set a write lock on my DB before a write operation and then unlock it. On searching I found that I can set the lock and unset using following steps

```
PRAGMA locking_mode = EXCLUSIVE
BEGIN EXCLUSIVE
COMMIT
```

But I couldn't find any example on the web. It would be really helpful if you can provide a small example as to how to execute these 3 operations for sqlite using C

Answer (score 2):

use sqlite3_exec with the dbHandle to execute the pragma

```
sqlite3_exec(handle, "PRAGMA locking_mode = EXCLUSIVE",0,0,0);
sqlite3_exec(handle, "BEGIN EXCLUSIVE",0,0,0);
sqlite3_exec(handle, "COMMIT",0,0,0);
```

*NOTE Error handling omitted*